# Are there any magic revisions similar to head for drive.revisions.list?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm looking for an easy way to get 1 revision before the current revision. Right now our app lists revisions, and then picks the second last one by timestamp.

I noticed that "head" is a magic revision for drive.revisions.get.
Are there other magic revisions available which can let me get one revision before "head"?

head-1 for example doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any more magic handles for revisions.